# If $f$ is a complex function with constant derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

If $f$ is a complex function with constant derivative, can I conclude that $f(z)=az+b$ for every $z \in \mathbb C$?

I think this is true, but I don't know if this needs a proof; I mean, if $f$ is a real valued function with this property, I know it is true.

Could a complex function have constant derivative and be different from a "linear" function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is connected.

Comment: Are you saying $f$ is constant on the whole plane $\Bbb C$? If so then yes you can conclude this (there can be more specific cases, but all of $\Bbb C$ certainly works).

Comment: @ Dave Yes, it is in the whole plane. But I want to know how to prove this. I mean, in real case you can use Mean Value Theorem or something... How it would be in $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 7):

If the function is holomorphic, you can integrate along any path. Then

$$F(x+iy)-F(0)=\int_0^x a\,dx+\int_x^{x+iy} a\,dy=a(x-0)+a(x+iy-x)=a(x+iy).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(z)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=a$$
then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=a$ gives us $f=ax+g(y)$ and $-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-ig'(y)=a$ says $g(y)=iay+b$ for a constant $b$. Then $f(z)=az+b$.